# DB2 [SQL0029] INTO clause missing from embedded statement

Tags: sql, database, db2, ibm-midrange, ibm-data-studio

UPDATE to my question. I found the answer and will edit the sample code. Thanks to those who tried to help me.

The following test script checks out okay in the tool "Run SQL Scripts" and with an online SQL Syntax checker. However, when deploying it as a Stored Procedure to a DB2 database on our IBM I using IBM Data Studio, it fails with the "[SQL0029] INTO clause missing from embedded statement". Searched far and wide in Google but nothing I found helped. Need a sanity check. What am I doing wrong?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE uspTotTripsCreatByAgtMoYr (
IN pForMonth    NUMERIC(2),
IN pForYear     NUMERIC(4)
)
    RESULT SETS 1
    LANGUAGE SQL

P1: BEGIN

-- Temp table.
DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE SESSION.tmpTTBA 
(
    UID CHAR(8) NOT NULL,
    NUMTRPCREATED   NUMERIC(6)  NOT NULL,
    ENDATEYR    NUMERIC(4)  NOT NULL,
    ENDATEMO    NUMERIC(2)  NOT NULL,
    DIVCODE CHAR(2) DEFAULT 'ZZ'
) WITH REPLACE ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

-- BEGIN PROOF OF CONCEPT
INSERT INTO SESSION.tmpTTBA (UID, NUMTRPCREATED, ENDATEYR, ENDATEMO)
SELECT  
    TM."RecordEntryUserID", 
    COUNT(TM."TripNumber"),
    TM."RecordEntryDateYear", 
    TM."RecordEntryDateMonth"   
FROM FXDTAZZ."TripMaster" "TM" 
GROUP BY TM."RecordEntryUserID",
    TM."RecordEntryDateYear",
    TM."RecordEntryDateMonth"
HAVING (TM."RecordEntryDateYear" = pForYear)     
AND (TM."RecordEntryDateMonth" = pForMonth);    

-- END PROOF OF CONCEPT

-- Sanity check POC
-- SELECT * FROM SESSION.tmpTTBA;
-- The previous SELECT line by itself is what was causing 
-- the SQL0029 error in the RUN SQL SCRIPT Editor. 
-- Here is the way to do it. Slaps himself in the forehead
-- for not figuring it out earlier. The important thing was
-- enclosing it in a new BEGIN...END routine block, along
-- with declaring and opening a cursor.
    BEGIN 
        DECLARE c_tmp CURSOR WITH RETURN TO CLIENT FOR           
            -- returns all rows
            SELECT * FROM SESSION.tmpTTBA;  
        OPEN c_tmp;
    END;

-- BEGIN AGGREGATION CODE FOR ALL SCHEMAS HERE
-- Start with FXDTAAA and loop to the end with FXDTAZZ

-- END AGGREGATION 

-- Clean up
DROP TABLE SESSION.tmpTTBA;
END P1
```

Comment: Should mention that if I remove the sanity check code, "SELECT * FROM SESSION.tmpTTBA;", the procedure compiles and runs successfully. So, I am befuddled with the SQL0029.

Comment: You can't "SELECT INTO nowhere" inside the routine. It was probably treated as useless statement by Db2 designers. The routine doesn't return any result set upon such a statement use, and this is why such a error is thrown upon an attempt to use this statement in a routine.

Comment: @MarkBarinstein Thanks for your reply but it went over my head. SELECT * FROM source is straightforward isn't it? Same as the INSERT INTO using a SELECT FROM statement which I know works because when I run the procedure I get number of rows inserted. All I'm trying to do now is dump what's in the temp table for a sanity check listing of inserted data.

Comment: it seem that on db2 nees a `SELECT INTO <variable`in order to have a destination for the select, else it points to nirwana

Comment: @GCDevOps `SELECT * FROM source` is straightforward in a *client* script, when you want to get the result set of this statement. If you want to make the routine running on the *server* to do the same (that is to return a result set back to the client), you must declare a cursor with the corresponding statement and `WITH RETURN` clause, declare you routine as returning the corresponding number of `DYNAMIC RESULT SETS`, open this cursor inside.

Comment: If you don't want to return a result set with the routine, just remove the select & drop statements from it and run them outside of the routine in the same session afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

this compiles. select into a variable. Not sure how it runs without returning a result set.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE uspTotTripsCreatByAgtMoYr (
IN pForMonth    NUMERIC(2),
IN pForYear     NUMERIC(4)
)
    RESULT SETS 1
    LANGUAGE SQL

P1: BEGIN

declare     vUid char(8) default ' ' ;

-- Temp table.
DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE SESSION.tmpTTBA 
(
    UID CHAR(8) NOT NULL,
    NUMTRPCREATED   NUMERIC(6)  NOT NULL,
    ENDATEYR    NUMERIC(4)  NOT NULL,
    ENDATEMO    NUMERIC(2)  NOT NULL,
    DIVCODE CHAR(2) DEFAULT 'ZZ'
) WITH REPLACE ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

-- BEGIN PROOF OF CONCEPT
INSERT INTO SESSION.tmpTTBA (UID, NUMTRPCREATED, ENDATEYR, ENDATEMO)
SELECT  
    TM."RecordEntryUserID", 
    COUNT(TM."TripNumber"),
    TM."RecordEntryDateYear", 
    TM."RecordEntryDateMonth"   
FROM FXDTAZZ."TripMaster" "TM" 
GROUP BY TM."RecordEntryUserID",
    TM."RecordEntryDateYear",
    TM."RecordEntryDateMonth"
HAVING (TM."RecordEntryDateYear" = pForYear)     
AND (TM."RecordEntryDateMonth" = pForMonth);    

-- END PROOF OF CONCEPT

-- Sanity check POC       
SELECT   uid              
into     vUid             
FROM     SESSION.tmpTTBA  
fetch first row only ;    

-- BEGIN AGGREGATION CODE FOR ALL SCHEMAS HERE
-- Start with FXDTAAA and loop to the end with FXDTAZZ

-- END AGGREGATION 

-- Clean up
DROP TABLE SESSION.tmpTTBA;
END P1
```

Comment: Thanks. It does compile alright in Data Studio. However, when testing it from Run SQL Scripts, it spits out the following error, and as usual, without a helpful line number reference to debug...    SQL State: 42802 Vendor Code: -117 Message: [SQL0117] Statement contains wrong number of values.

Comment: DB2 error messages can be brutal. Use process of elimination to isolate which statement is causing the error.